# Random-delay gen

Tags: transistors, capacitor, digital-logic

Some years ago I tried to design a circuit where (among other things) a LED flashes after a kinda random delay. As it didn't work, (and after raging and destroying everything that could help me solve the problem) I am wondering if there was a fundamental mistake or I was just too sloppy.

Today, I finally found a print of the circuit (the digital version is lost anyway) so that I, at least, can ask for help.

Picture of the circuit:

[image: schematic diagram]

(Hope you're not confused by the european symbols...)

By unplugging the counter IC ([7474](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/rcem/~ahogan/327/7474.pdf)), everything is working as it should (just with constant delay): by pressing the first button, the belonging LED lights up till the LED "D4" flashes.

Therefore, just the upper half of the circuit is interesting for me. Without the counter IC the delay is generated by the capacitor "C1". My intention was that, by grounding the other 2 capacitors (C2 and C3), the capacity (and the delay time) is tripled.
As the counter IC is supplied with nearly the same voltage as the capacitors, the 2 capacitors (C2 and C3) should only influence the circuit while the counter IC doesn't output TRUE

The outputs of the counter IC should be random, as the counters are set by oscillators (made with IC2)

Comment: Wow, that's a long way to go to avoid using a microcontroller.  A PIC 10F200, bypass cap, resistor, and LED can do this.

Comment: I expected that my solution isn't the easiest way, but that was a project for school, where I wasn't allowed to use microcontrollers. Moreover this would be too easy I think.
But thank's for this hint. Never heard of such tiny µC :D

Comment: You need to work on your schematic a bit.  You've mostly done a nice of of obfuscating the circuit, but if I look at it closely I can still figure it out in a few places.

Comment: And to add to Olin's point... A pic10f200 is like $0.50 in single quantity, has an internal 4mhz oscillator, and can sink well enough current to drive an led.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the counter IC is supplied with nearly the same voltage as the
>   capacitors, the 2 capacitors (C2 and C3) should only influence the
>   circuit while the counter IC doesn't output TRUE

This is your false assumption. C2 and C3 have the same capacitance, and the same effect on the timer circuit, regardless of whether their negative ends are held at 0V or 5V.

Note that when they are at 5V, you are reverse-biasing the capacitors, which can potentially damage them (but probably not too badly at 5V).

Comment: Somehow that makes sense to me...
But why isn't the circuit at least working with constant delay, when the IC is plugged?

Comment: I don't know ... you never said what kind of delays you were getting in that configuration. Perhaps there was enough leakage current through C2 and C3 to disrupt the operation of the timer. Also, when the counter switches states, it will force current through those two capacitors that affects the charge on C1.